# SSRS 2008: how to change chart axis unit dynamically?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, scale, axis-labels

I have a chart in SSRS report and its Y-Axis shows total revenue from salesman. The unit for Y-Axis is "Million" and it works perfect for total amount.

However, there are about thousands of salesman and when one particular salesman is selected in parameter panel, his/her sales amount may only be at "hundred" level. Thus, the bar on chart would be too small to identify.

Is there any way to change Y-Axis Unit dynamically during the running time?

Comment: Your best bet is calculate a max value based on percentage and calculate the values based on a percentage of the max. Your y-axis max values can move and your percentages of the maximum can move per row.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you've seen, in the Chart designer you can set **Show Values in**, but you can't make this expression-based:

[image]

However, if you look at the **Properties** for the **Chart Axis**, you can that this corresponds to a property **LabelsFormat** which ***is*** expression-based:

[image]

So when you choose Millions in the chart designer the format expression will look something like:

```
0,,;(0,,)
```

and Thousands will look something like:

```
0,;(0,)
```

Based on this, you can make **LabelsFormat** expression-based taking into account the data:

```
=IIf(Max(Fields!TotalSales.Value) > 100000, "0,,;(0,,)", "0,;(0,)")
```

It's probably also useful to update the **Axis Title** accordingly, something like:

```
=IIf(Max(Fields!TotalSales.Value) > 100000, "Sales (Millions)", "Sales (thousands)")
```

Consider a simple DataSet and chart:

[image]

[image]

The Axis gets updated appropriately depending on the underlying data:

[image]

[image]

You'll obviously need to adapt to your particular data but hopefully this points you in the correct direction.